# Local Admins on SQL Server systems

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need to monitor the local admins on my SQL Server systems for auditing. Is there a way to use a stored procedure with powershell to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this stored procedure to collect the local admins on the system as long as it runs under the context of a member of the sysadmin role.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create procedure [dbo].[usp_CollectLocalAdmins]
as
-- list all members of Local Administrators group
set nocount on
declare @tsql nvarchar(1000)
create table #Output (output varchar(1000))
set @tsql=  'xp_cmdshell ''powershell -c "$([ADSI]''''WinNT://' + @@servername + '/Administrators,group'''').psbase.Invoke(''''Members'''') | foreach { $_.GetType().InvokeMember(''''ADspath'''', ''''GetProperty'''', $null, $_, $null).Replace(''''WinNT://'''', '''''''') }"'''

insert into #Output
    exec sp_executesql @tsql
select 
    @@servername ServerName,
    output MemberName 
from #Output o

drop table #output
go
```

Comment: Wouldn’t' it be easier just to use the powershell without it being inside a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use Powershell for this, which would require xp_cmdshell in a stored procedure. Just use xp_logininfo. As long as you add the group to SQL Server (you don't have to give it any permissions), you can query the members of it.

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_logininfo 'Builtin\Administrators', 'members'
```